# Heat map for Irregularly Spaced Data with No Interpolation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to plot a heatmap where the input data is not in the typical rectangularly spaced grid. Here is some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
xmin = 6
xmax= 12
ymin = 0

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
ymax = x**2
final = []

for i in range(len(ymax)):

    yrange = np.linspace(0, ymax[i], 100)

    for j in range(len(yrange)):
        intensity = np.random.rand()
        final.append([x[i], yrange[j], intensity])
    
    
    
data_for_plotting = np.asarray(final) # (10000, 3) shaped array
```

I would like to plot intensity (in the colorbar) as a function of (x,y) which represents the position and I would like to do this without interpolation.

Here is my solution which uses matplotlib's griddata and linear interpolation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

total_length = 100
x1 = np.linspace(min(data_for_plotting[:,0]), max(data_for_plotting[:,0]), total_length)
y1 = np.linspace(min(data_for_plotting[:,1]), max(data_for_plotting[:,1]), total_length)
z1 = griddata(data_for_plotting[:,0], data_for_plotting[:,1], data_for_plotting[:,2], x1, y1, interp='linear')
p=plt.pcolormesh(x1, y1, z1,  vmin = 0. , vmax=1.0, cmap='viridis')
clb = plt.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

I am looking for an alternate solution without interpolation as I would like to see the smallest unit of measurement in my x and y position (pixel size/rectangle). Based on the sample data given above I expect the height of the pixel to increase for large values of x.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what `matplotlib.mlab.griddata` is about. Maybe some very old version?

You could use [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) which needs its parameters in a slightly different format. `method='nearest'` switches off the interpolation (default `method='linear'`).

Here is how it could look with your test data (see griddata's documentation for more explanation and examples):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np

xmin = 6
xmax = 12
ymin = 0
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
ymax = x ** 2
final = []
for i in range(len(ymax)):
    yrange = np.linspace(0, ymax[i], 100)
    for j in range(len(yrange)):
        intensity = np.random.rand()
        final.append([x[i], yrange[j], intensity])
data_for_plotting = np.asarray(final)  # (10000, 3) shaped array

total_length = 100
x1 = np.linspace(min(data_for_plotting[:, 0]), max(data_for_plotting[:, 0]), total_length)
y1 = np.linspace(min(data_for_plotting[:, 1]), max(data_for_plotting[:, 1]), total_length)
grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
z1 = griddata(data_for_plotting[:, :2], data_for_plotting[:, 2], (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
img = plt.imshow(z1, extent=[x1[0], x1[-1], y1[0], y1[-1]], origin='lower',
                 vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='inferno', aspect='auto')
cbar = plt.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: griddata with imshow]

An alernative, is to create one rectangle for each of the prolonged pixels.  Beware that this can be a rather slow operation. If really needed, one could create a `pcolormesh` for each column.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

# ... create x and data_for_plotting as before 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')
norm = plt.Normalize(0, 1)
x_step = x[1] - x[0]
y_step = 0
for i, (xi, yi, intensity_i) in enumerate(data_for_plotting):
    if i + 1 < len(data_for_plotting) and data_for_plotting[i + 1, 0] == xi:  # when False, the last y_step is reused
        y_step = data_for_plotting[i + 1, 1] - yi
    ax.add_artist(plt.Rectangle((xi, yi), x_step, y_step, color=cmap(norm(intensity_i))))
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
ax.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1])
ax.set_ylim(0, data_for_plotting[:, 1].max())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: colormesh with unequal rectangles]

Comment: By gridding the data either by using scipy or matplotlib.mlab we are assuming an interpolation function for eg linear or plotting the "nearest" available data point as you showed. Is there a way to plot the actual data itself before gridding? The first rectangle would have length data_for_plotting[:, 0][100] - data_for_plotting[:, 0][0] and width data_for_plotting[:, 1][1] - data_for_plotting[:, 1][0] and highlight the entire rectangle with a color corresponding to the value of data_for_plotting[:, 2][0] and repeat this for every point and mask areas in the plot where no data exists.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to see the pixel size (length x breadth) from the actual data.